# Cubic equation in term of quadratic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, cubics

I have somehow find a way to find solutions of cubic equation by first converting it to quadratic equations .It's a bit embarrassing that I used cubic formula to do so.My question is that is my method correct and if yes can I calculate roots of cubic equation which has complex solutions by this method.So what I have done is
Let there be a cubic equation

A$x^3$+B$x^2$+Cx+D=0........(1)

Let there be a quadratic equation which has same solution as equation 1and it's $x^2$coefficient be equal to A i.e the coefficient of $x^3$ in equation 1.So our quadratic equation is

A$x^2$+bx+c=0..........(2)

Writing both equations together and multiplying equation (2) by x we get

A$x^3$+B$x^2$+Cx+D=0........(3)

A$x^3$+b$x^2$+cx=0...........(4)

Subtracting 4 from 3 we get

B$x^2$-b$x^2$+Cx-cx+D=0

$x^2$(B-b)+x(C-c)+D=0............(5)

Now equation 2 and 5 have same solutions and both are quadratic so we can multiply coefficient of 5 by a factor k such that it comes equal to coefficients of equation (2) so

(B-b)k=A...........(6)

(C-c)k=b..........(7)

Dk=c

k=$\frac{c}{D}$..........(8)

Putting value from 8 in 6 and 7 we get

$\frac{(B-b)c}{D}$=A

$\frac{(C-c)c}{D}$=b

c=$\frac{AD}{B-b}$...........(9)

b=$\frac{c(C-c)}{D}$..........(10)

Now what I have done is that I have substituted value of c from (9) in equation (10)and come up with a cubic equation

$b^3$-$b^2$2B+b($B^2$+CA)+$A^2$D-ABC=0.

Now here is the funny and embarrassing part I have calculated value of b from cubic formula to be

b=($(R+$($Q^3$+$R^2$)^$\frac{1}{2}$)^$\frac{1}{3}$)+($(R-$($Q^3$+$R^2$)^$\frac{1}{2}$)^$\frac{1}{3}$)+$\frac{2B}{3}$..............11

where R=$\frac{9ABC-2$B^3$-27$A^2$D}{54}$

Q=$\frac{3CA-$B^2$}{9}$

So now cubic equation will have solutions equal to the solutions of quadratic equation

A$x^2$+bx+c=0 i.e

A$x^2$+bx +$\frac{AD}{B-b}$

and b can be calculated from equation 11,when 2 roots are calculated 3rd root can also be calculated by dividing polynomial .I know this method is quite long but I want to ask is this method correct or not and if correct can this method give solutions of all cubic equations

Comment: Your first problem is declaring that a quadratic, which has two solutions, has the same solutions as a cubic, which has three solutions.  Unless two of the cubic roots happen to be equal, this is not possible.

Comment: I calculated roots of some cubic equations and corresponding quadratic equation and roots are coming to be equal

Comment: If you used the cubic formula to calculate the roots in $b$ then you have created a bootstrap problem for yourself.

Comment: So can I say that my method is correct and of some value???

Comment: By bootstrap you mean??

Comment: That's why I wrote funny and embarrassing for me